# Unable to Accept User Input In Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

please I am new to dart and I want to create a simple program to accept two numbers from the user and sum up the two numbers.

However, when I run the code below, I encounter into an error.

**Code**

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
print("enter num1: ");
String num1 = stdin.readLineSync();
print("enter num2: ");
String num2 = stdin.readLineSync();
print(int.parse(num1) + int.parse(num2));

}
```

**Screenshot**

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uyqsy.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stdin.readLineSync();` may return null if no input is given.

You variable expects only values of the type String on the other hand.

Fix this by adding a **?** at the end of your variable name to make it nullable:

```
String? num1 = stdin.readLineSync();
```

Before using it later make sure it is not null:

```
if (num1 != null) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: It worked! 

By the way, I was following this tutorial on youtube, here's the instructors code.

 https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQECh.png

My problem is, I tried running the same code in my editor and encountered an error.

Comment: He uses an older dart version, null safety came with dart version 2.12: https://dart.dev/null-safety